# Single Linked List addition fault

Tags: c++, data-structures

The function to add a new list item in a single linked list

```cpp
void linked_list::push(int n) {
    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp->data = n;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    } 
    else {
        tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
}
```

and for display, I used the following function code

```cpp
void linked_list::display() {
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "Empty list" <<endl;
    }
    else {
        node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            cout << tmp->data << " ";
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

after passing some values i.e 1 2 3 4 my expected output is all the values given but it gives the following output i.e. 1 2 3

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please!

Comment: `while(tmp->next != NULL)` or `while(tmp != NULL)`? Please take some time to think about the difference between those two.

Comment: Also note that `NULL` is really a C backward compatible macro. In modern C++ code you should be using `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to print them all out, condition inside while has to be: 
 **while(tmp != NULL)**

```cpp
void linked_list::display() {
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "Empty list" << endl;
    }
    else {
        node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            cout << tmp->data << " ";
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```